# Can a reference of an interface = null?

Tags: java, android, interface, reference

I read this code in a book just now.

```
public class AdapterWrapper implements ListAdapter {
  ListAdapter delegate=null;

  // other code

}
```

The `ListAdapter` is a public interface and a reference of that interface has been made and assigned null. Is this valid? I'm really confused by this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's valid. It just means that `delegate` is a reference to `ListAdapter` interface and it's currently pointing at `null`.

You can later make it point to **any** class implementing the `ListAdapter` interface, such as `SimpleCursorAdapter`, `WrapperListAdapter` or any other implementation you want.

Using an interface type as reference is useful when you don't know ahead of time what class is it going to be at runtime. So you just use a reference pointing to an interface.

Answer (score 2):

The *variable* has a value, which is a null reference. There's nothing problematic about this.

The value of any reference type variable is either a reference to an instance of some compatible type, or null - that's the same for both classes and interfaces.

Comment: ErichLancaster: Yes, and interfaces never directly exist as objects. Objects are always created from some class that may implement interfaces. Therefore, your interface variable will either contain a reference to some object of a class implementing this interface or null.

Answer (score 2):

Just quoting Wikipedia on [Interface(Java)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29) here:

> Object references in Java may be specified to be of an interface type;
>   in which case, they must either be null, or be bound to an object that
>   implements the interface.

So the code seems valid by this definition.